# how to remote desktop from windows using rdp

Tags: system, greeter, rdp

Trying to remote from windows to the linux box.
After entering username and password the rdp session disconnects and throws me out back to windows

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the out-of-the-box configuration, or did you install and configure a RDP-compatible service, like xRDP?

RDP is a Microsoft protocol and isn't enabled on most (any?) Linux distributions that I'm aware of by default. If you would like to enable your Linux GUI desktop with access through RDP, I suggest following [a guide like this one](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-and-use-xrdp-server-remote-desktop-on-linux-system/) starting at Step 2. Or, you could try a separate remote desktop program like [NoMachine](https://knowledgebase.nomachine.com/DT11R00174#2.2). It's proprietary, but I think it works great if you really need it... fast performance, reliable, and easy to use!

I can't in good consciousness mention remote access to a Linux box without also asking, do you really need to interact with the GUI desktop? If simply having access to the command line is enough, then Windows 10, macOS, and Linux OS are already pre-loaded with a SSH client that you can use to connect.

And, if you want to get fancier and really leverage the 'nix experience, you could use a MS Windows implementation of an x11 client to connect. Check out [xpra](http://xpra.org/) for a project that's been around for a long time, or [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) for a complete suite of remote access tools for Windows that can even run as a portable application without any installation.

Comment: Ubuntu and Fedora 2022 (GNOME) come with RDP support out-of-the-box.